# Keyboard in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox

My buddy is running Oracle VirtualBox, and everything works fine - except for the fact that the backslash ( `\` ) key on a Swiss-German keyboard doesn't work - instead you're getting a vertical bar ( `|` ) - which is really quite annoying if you're trying to type in UNC paths....

The `\` on a Swiss-German keyboard is on the key with the `<` and `>` signs - you need to press `Alt Gr` or `Alt+Ctrl` to get it. Is there any way to teach VirtualBox that we're using a Swiss German keyboard and that it should respect the keyboard layout??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to tell VirtualBox anything. You need to configure the guest OS to recognize the Swiss German keyboard instead. Since you didn't mention what guest OS you're running, I can't help you to figure out how to do that, I'm afraid.

If your guest OS is Windows, you configure the keyboard and language using the Control Panel's Regional and Language Options, Languages tab.

Comment: Guest OS is Win7 - and it **is** configured for Swiss-German keyboard - but inside VirtualBox, some keys are strangely remapped and don't work properly - the backslash just being the most annoying of those...

Comment: Did you install the Guest Additions on VirtualBox? I don't have any strange keymappings on either Ubuntu or Win7 inside VirtualBox (but I'm not using a Swiss German keyboard, either).